# Arduino search network for an IP address and get the MAC address

Tags: arduino, mac-address

I am looking for a way to get the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of an [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) in [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and print that to serial. Is there a way to do that?

I know how to print the line. I just really need the function to get the MAC address of an IP address.

(FYI, I don't need the MAC address of an Arduino [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields).)

Comment: I started a project on Github with Arduino Uno and the Ethernet shield (W5100). https://github.com/powtac/Autarc_LAN_User_Stats/ The goal is to identify all users in a network and make some stats out of it. Therefor I'm also searching for an "IP to MAC" functionality!

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address is not local, [you cannot do this](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/tcpip/f/convertmacipadd.htm) in principle (Arduino or not). See also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/349256/theory-regarding-mac-and-ip-address-in-network-packet-and-frame-content).

If the IP address is local, then if you have a server that you can use for this, you can connect to it from your Arduino, and have the server do the IP address-to-MAC lookup, and give that to your Arduino. It looks like neither the [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) nor the Ethernet library support such lookups.